# Angular 5 browser(Chrome, Edge, Mozilla, Opera, Safari) minimum support

Tags: angular, cross-browser, version

Can anyone provide me with the list of minimum browser support for Angular 5? I've searched them on the angular official [site](https://angular.io/guide/browser-support). But all I got is the "the word latest" for chrome, Mozilla, Edge and no information about Opera, Safari.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shows you here: https://github.com/angular/angular

Scroll down to the readme.md section as shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

angular x.x version support browser version

```
npx browserslist
```